# Common or centralised dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to use a common or centralised dictionary in python. I have several scripts that work on the same data sets, but do different things. I have dictionarys in these scripts (e.g. instrument name) that are used in more than one script. If I make changes or add values I have to make shure I do this in all scripts, which is of course painfull and prone for errors.

Is there a possibility, that I have one dictionary and use it in all the different scripts?

Any help is appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Write the dict in it's own file and import it ?

Comment: different scripts = different processes.
will they share memory? If the data are read only then it will work but if you modify the data in one script?
I think @pcalcao is correct

Comment: Jochens suggestion is what I am doing now. A very nice example by FallenAngle - thanks to all for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such situations, I have a `general_values.py` file in my project root.

Since lists and [`dictionaries`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) are all use reference to store values, using the same `dict` or `list` in different scripts do not cause problems since they all will use the same single data stored in memory.

Likwise:

```
main_values.py

    my_dict = {1:1}

some.py

    import main_values
    main_values.my_dict[2] = 2

other.py

    import main_values
    print  main_values.my_dict

    >> {1:1, 2:2}
```

Comment: All answers were helpful. I was expecting something along this line, but just could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't exactly understand if you're talking about several scripts running in the same process, or several processes that need to share the same data:

**Several processes:**

I think the simplest way of doing this, sharing data between several scripts (different processes), is to use a simple file database.

SQLite3 comes bundled with Python, so that would be a good choice.

**Single process:**

If you simply want to centralize the access of several methods running at the same time (within the same process), then you can declare your dictionary in one script, and have all the others access that one location, without duplicating the structure.
You basically declare this dict in a script, and import it in all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- You could use a shared shelved file. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html
- You could store configuration information in a JSON/YAML or similar file
- It may be overkill for your usecase, but something like http://redis.io (or a lightweight key store) database will enable you to use a `dict`-like interface to persist keys across processes and be available to other languages.